# What status code should I return when part of a bulk update fails?

Tags: rest, http, web

Let's say I'm a server responding to a request to do a bulk create of some entity. Let's say that I've also decided to make it so that if one instance of the entity can't be created, due to a server error or user error, I will still create the other entity instances. In this scenario what should I return? A 201 because I created most of the entities in the request? Or A 4xx/5xx since there was an error while creating one of the entities?

Answer (score 2):

If you return a 4xx code it implies that the entire request has failed, and the server-state has not changed.

If the intent of the request is to do 'one or more things and some may fail', then a partial application is still a success, so that puts in the 2XX range.

`206` is not a good idea. This is specifically for requests that use `Range`, which is not the case here.

`207` *could* be used. You'll probably want to define a custom format instead of the default XML-based on. My vote would probably just go to `200`.

Also, consider just doing many requests. Requests are cheap, why lump them together? Now each request can have their own beautiful, accurate status code.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you could return a [multi-status (207)](https://httpstatuses.com/207) response where you acknowledge the result for each batch entry. That way the client would have a complete awareness of the results. However, that type of HTTP status involves more complex processing on the client-side.

Answer (score -1):

I think 201 is not a good choice because it says "Accepted" which mean everything is alright. But not in your case. Maybe 206 is a good idea which means "Partial Content" according to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) "The server is delivering only part of the resource..."

Comment: I do not know why this was downvoted. It acutally makes sense to me to return acknowledgement of successful batch entries in a 206 status code and then proceed with a 4xx for the errors in the rest. And I totally agree that 201 is not OK when things went wrong on the server.